# Add commits against JIRA using REST API?

Tags: git, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, aws-codecommit

I am trying to add commits to Jira issue using rest api, but i cannot find an api to do that. There is a [GET api](https://(jira-instance)/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=(issueid)&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository) but no POST or PUT.

The reason I am trying to do this is, there is no plugin to add AWS CodeCommit's commit to JIRA, and i am trying to write my own. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To my knowledge JIRA has no such endpoint - simply because it has no commits, so creating one in JIRA doesn't make sense. A plugin in JIRA can show commits on other systems, but other systems can't add them from the outside.

Comment: By commits, i meant commits under a JIRA ticket, each ticket would have a development section and it would have the branch name and the commits. i am trying to add AWS codecommit's commit to the development section of JIRA.

Comment: Issue properties perhaps? We wrote our own REST API and used an AO database to store the info for an inhouse app

Comment: you mean when we update issue properties, we can update commit details too?